# Postfix+Maildrop: Error opening /etc/maildroprc

Tags: postfix, email

I just created the  /etc/maildroprc file to drop spam mails into a spamfolder. In my postfix master.cf I have the line:

```
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
```

The permissions of the /etc/maildroprc file look like this: (ls -l)

```
-rw------- vmail vmail /etc/maildroprc
```

The vmail user is in /etc/passwd :

```
vmail:x:5000:5000::/home/vmail:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

The problem is that every time an email is being processed the following error occurs in postfix (/var/log/mail.log):

```
(temporary failure. Command output: /usr/bin/maildrop: Error opening /etc/maildroprc. )
```

Do you have any idea what could be the reason for this behavior?

**Edit:** The contents of my maildroprc file (I changed it to this minimum and it didn't change anything on the error)

```
# Global maildrop filter file

# Uncomment this line to make maildrop default to ~/Maildir for
# delivery- this is where courier-imap (amongst others) will look.
DEFAULT="$HOME/Maildir"
```

**Edit 2:** 
The following command exits normally (executed as root)

```
maildrop -V < /testspam.txt
```

where this command throws the same error as postfix: (also executed as root)

```
maildrop -V -d myusername < /testspam.txt
```

**Edit 3:**
It seems to be a permission problem. If I change the permission of /etc/maildroprc to 777 everything works. Any idea on how the permissions really should look like?

Comment: What is the content of your `maildroprc` file?

Comment: I added the contents but I don't think this is the reason for the error.

Comment: can you try `chgrp vmail /usr/bin/maildrop; chmod 2755 /usr/bin/maildrop; chgrp vmail /etc/maildroprc; chmod 660 /etc/maildroprc` and see if this fix it?

Comment: tried it but that doesn't fix it. still the same error

Comment: @fboaventura Ok ... changed my master.cf back such that maildrop is executed by the vmail user (had changed it to root). Now your suggestion works! Thanks

Comment: Posted the suggestion as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try

```
chgrp vmail /usr/bin/maildrop
chmod 2755 /usr/bin/maildrop
chgrp vmail /etc/maildroprc
chmod 660 /etc/maildroprc
```

and see if this fix it?